# How to change antd pro editable table default warning message or it's language?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have install ant-design-pro 5.0.0 in my react project. But in the Editable pro table component, I couldn't change the warning message or its language. Even though I have defined the default language as English for some of the parts it is still showing Chinese
[Editable pro table warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WWyw.png)

Comment: Your answer: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670439/how-to-change-button-text-in-the-editableprotable-in-ant-design-pro)

Comment: Your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670439/how-to-change-button-text-in-the-editableprotable-in-ant-design-pro